# Is it possible that B+ Tree will delete a number from its leaf node, but not from internal node?

Tags: database, b-tree

I had an assignment where I must be adding and deleting operations from a B+ Tree. I realized there were some numbers that are present in nonleaf nodes, but not in the leaf nodes. I immediately asked my teaching assistant that "How can a B+ tree contain an element that is not present in any of its leaf nodes?". His response was "I imagined that the numbers that are not present in leaf nodes but present in nonleaf nodes are deleted elements."

Is it possible?
Don't we delete every occurrence of an element from B+ tree while we are deleting it?

If it is possible, could you give an example of insertion and deletion sequence where this situation occurs?

Answer (score 0):

B+-trees can be implemented in different ways regarding the keys used at non-leaf nodes.

The purpose of these keys is to support the lookup, i.e., the only constraint is that the intervals defined by the keys at each non-leaf node are consistent with the actual keys found at descendant leaf nodes.

Reusing keys found at leaf nodes as the keys at non-leaf nodes is a possible practice and is convenient, because it avoids arbitrarily "making up" non-leaf keys, however it is not a requirement of B+-trees. In particular, when deleting leaf keys or nodes, it would cause an unnecessary overhead to update all ancestor non-leaf keys, and it is more efficient not to do it.

Another possible practice would be to use prefixes of the leaf keys, similar in spirit to (but not the same as) [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 0):

The answer you got is correct. Here is an example of a B+ tree with order (maximum branching factor) 4:

[image]

To know which keys the tree contains, one only needs to look at the bottom level and follow the (optional) links from one node to the next: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

The 3 and 5 in the non-leaf node do not serve as data, but as separators. They indicate that:

- values in the left-most leaf are less than 3
- values in the middle leaf are greater than or equal to 3, and less than 5
- values in the right-most leaf are greater than or equal to 5.

When only insertions have happened, these separators will match a key that occurs in the bottom layer, but this can change when a key is deleted.

For instance, if we delete key 5, the involved leaf node will just shift it out, and nothing more needs to be updated:

[image]

The constraints in the bullet list above are still correct, and that's all that matters.